# Liquibase rollback is not intelligent to determine the order of statements to execute. Is that correct?

Tags: database, oracle, rollback, liquibase

I have a process followed where each change made to the db is updated in its own sql file and the sql file is referred inside its own changeset.xml. For example table1.sql has a table1.xml which uses `<sql>` tag to refer to that sql. The table1.sql has some change for the table1 object on the database.

Assume there are a bunch of objects being updated, a trigger referencing table1, a package spec and body referencing table1 and a constraint referencing table1. The sql statements for these objects are in their respective sql files like trigger1.sql referred inside trigger1.xml , constraint1.sql referred inside constraint1.xml etc..

Now the rollback statements for the respective xmls focus only about that object. For example, trigger1.xml has rollback tag just to drop trigger1 and similarly constrain1.xml has rollback tag only to drop constraint1.

All the changelog xmls are sequenced inside a master xml which determines the update order like including first table1.xml, constrain1.xml, trigger1.xml etc..

My question is, I am stuck with either this approach or liquibase itself because, the rollbackSQL command does not generate the sqls in the right order like drop trigger first, drop constraint first and then finally drop the table1. Assume a bigger scenario of complex changes interdependent on other objects that cannot be rolledback because the order is not intelligent enough.

How to handle this situation? Is there a different approach recommended?

Comment: You should straighten your question to make it easier to read if you want more answers. I think liquibase will execute the rollback statements in reverse order. Are you saying that this does not happen? Or are you expecting liquibase to figure out a smart way (not just reverse)?

Comment: @Jens. I thought my question was already straight forward, anyways.. my question again is to understand if liquibase is designed only to reverse the order of changes in the rollback script or does it also have capabilities to figure out in which order the rollback has to be executed?

Comment: Your comment is much shorter and easier to understand. :-) Nevermind. I think other then executing all changesets in reverse order when `rollback` is done liquibase does not have any "smart" capabilities. Though I have to say that I don't oversee the whole liquibase code and functionality - so I could be wrong. BUT: `rollback` can be ouput to a file (rather then executing it directly to the database) with `rollbackSQL`. Then you re-order them yourself. Not super-convenient but a way to go.

Comment: I did a lot of searching in google and in stackoverflow to see if there is any DB Change management solution that embraces DevOps model. I am trying to use Liquibase to consolidate DB changes from multiple teams and apply them directly on target databases without any manual intervention. Though it allows me to capture failures and report it as feedback to the team, the rollback feature in Liquibase is not fully equipped enough to automate application of DB changes to target DB and rolling them back. This puts me in the spot to find work arounds in using Liquibase. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself at all but [Datical](http://www.datical.com/) is based  on liquibase and adds more functionality to it. Nathan Voxland (creator of liquibase) seem to work there as well. It is commercial and they have no infos on the page at what it costs (at least I was not able to find infos when I did a quick search). But maybe it's worth to be considered.

Comment: @Jens you are correct that Nathan does work for Datical (I do as well). Pricing for Datical is based on a number of different factors - contact our sales team if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct - Liquibase does not make any attempt to re-order changesets. They run in the order they are listed in the changelog.